# Android Alert Dialog crashes my application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever I debug the application it crashes when I click the button that pops up the dialog.

What should I do to make that dialog work?

```
 public class Actionbar_BtnHandler extends Activity {
    Context context;

    public  Actionbar_BtnHandler (Context context)
    {

        this.context=context;
    }
    public void btn_handler (Button btn_mic,Button btn_post)
    {
        btn_mic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context,"MICROPHONE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btn_post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    // Get the layout inflater
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

                    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
                    // Add action buttons
                           .setPositiveButton("Post", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   // sign in the user ...
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               }
                           });      
                     builder.create();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflatter.from(context);

Answer (score 3):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
```

is inaccurate... The cast seems to fail

Try :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = Actionbar_BtnHandler.this.getLayoutInflater();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this write your AlertDialog code using Handler..

```
 btn_post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.post(MessagealertDisplay);
    }
});
}





Runnable MessagealertDisplay = new Runnable() { 

    @Override
    public void run() {

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
            // Add action buttons
                   .setPositiveButton("Post", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           // sign in the user ...
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       }
                   });      
             builder.create();

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i used 
Actionbar_BtnHandler btns = new Actionbar_BtnHandle(Class.this);
          btns.btn_handler(btn_post, btn_mic);
instead of
Actionbar_BtnHandler btns = new Actionbar_BtnHandler(getApplicationContext);
          btns.btn_handler(btn_post, btn_mic);
and it worked